# Safari remember password of all sites after upgrading to 7.0.2

Tags: safari, password

I upgraded to `Mavericks 9.0.2` the day it was released. I recently found that Safari now asks if I want it to remember passwords on all sites, including sites that I explicitly chose **not** to remember passwords, like banks. Is this the normal behavior of the updated Safari, or is something wrong with my Mac?

My Safari version is `7.0.2 (9537.74.9)`

Answer (score -3):

It sounds like it is a new version of Safari. If you don't like it, there is always Chrome!